# Android web application question

Tags: android

I'd like to start writing my first android web application . It's supposed to be quite a bold project involving OpenLayer ,Javascript and JSON. So my question is should this kind of project be build using WebViews  or should it involve the browser ?

Personally I have in mind a stand alone application, but from what I've read WebViews are quite a poor choice when it comes to Javascript and web applications. So how does one procedes in such cases ?

Comment: what's an "android web application"???

Comment: Perhaps things are a little bit confused in my head , but I was thinking to a web application fitted to run in the android browser when I mentioned "android web application"

Comment: Something like this: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply creating a standalone App with a WebView is like creating a own Browser for your Web-Project. Why don't you optimize your web-stuff for the lower screen-resolutions of Android Devices?

Because a WebView is an Instance of the Android Browser.

Answer (score 1):

You should try out [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/). Involves building your app inside WebViews using HTML5, JS and CSS3. Huge plus is that you can use the same code for iOS and other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

checkout for wikitude sdk simplearbrowser sample project on www.wikitude.com and download sdk trial version and run sample project u will get the idea about the browser with webview in android.